# Which resolution should AudioItem.albumArt have?

Tags: bixby

The [AudioItem structure](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.audio#audioitem) has a required attribute *albumArtUrl*.

Which resolution should the image at this URL have?

Is the resolution different for different targets e.g. mobile, fridge, tv?

Comment: The resolution is largely left to your discretion for providing your users with the best content for their device(s). However, I am confirming internally if there are any specific requirements and, if so, what they are. I will update you as soon as I know more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Mobile target, the UI is 96dp X 96dp so that would be the minimum recommended resolution.

However, there are no specific requirements for the resolution of images defined in this property. We recommend that you test them out on the device or the corresponding Simulator view to ensure that your users are presented with the most crisp and clear images on the devices you plan to support.

Comment: Thank you. Please note, that in the simulator, the albumArt is always displayed at the same resolution, regardless of the target. However, testing on a device is fine.